# Execute Javascript function oninit in Framework7 on index page - Cordova

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

On the app start I want to execute a JavaScript Function.

I tried to work on this with index as having - data-page="index" and using below function:

```
myApp.onPageInit('index', function (page) {
  // "page" variable contains all required information about loaded and initialized page 
})
```

But this function doesn't work when the application is just started.

Comment: Did you tried cordova device ready method?

Comment: Yes but with framework7 it has some issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger it.

```
myApp.onPageInit('index', function() {
    // Code here
}).trigger();
```

Use `.trigger()` only for index route. You can read more in framework7 documentation.

**Update**

You can also check the [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/28) conversation in framework7 github repo.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try this:

```
window.onload = function(){   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); }

function onDeviceReady() { // your device ready logic here }
```

**Edit:**

We can do this in pure JavaScript (although this will not work in all browsers):

> var doSomething = function (event) { . . . };
>
> window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doSomething);

But we can do it more easily with jQuery, and it will work cross-browser:

> $(window).ready(doSomething);

This can be shortened further to:

> $(doSomething);

In all the above examples, doSomething is a JavaScript function.

Comment: documentready and deviceready do not necessarily fire in the sequence you describe.

Comment: an anonymous function will have the same effect as your edit without the overhead. Cordova on the other hand does not fire the events in any given order so they must be handled in a quasi sequential manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    // Your content here
});
```

For

```
$$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     // Your content here
});
```